# Задействование математического сопроцессора (FPU)

Tags: c++, ассемблер, double

В ходе выполнения некоторого задания возникла необходимость вычислить некоторую с задействованием математического сопроцессор посредством ассемблерных команд и сравнить со значением, вычисляемым функцией, написанной на высокоуровневом ЯП (C++). Суть вопроса: посредством ассемблера задействуется непосредственно сам сопроцессор, но задействуется ли он при выполнении функции, написанной на С++? Работа производилась с числами в формате double, то есть, с плавающей запятой.

Comment: Если под FPU имеется в виду в узком смысле x87, то в 64-х разрядном коде он может и не использоваться, будет задействован SSE модуль

Comment: Код 32-х разрядный, спасибо за информацию)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть такая возможность - да.

В свое время процессор и сопроцессор были буквально физически разными вещами, и тогдашние компиляторы могли - по запросу - скомпилировать код как с применением сопроцессора, так и с применением библиотек, эту работу сопроцессора эмулирующих.

Но в нынешнее время этот вопрос вряд ли актуален. По-моему, уже компилятор с поддержкой эмуляции сопроцессора не найти...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: В режиме отладки наблюдал изменения стека сопроцессора, как при исполнении ассемблерных команд, что, в принципе, естественно, ведь так и должно быть, так и при исполнении кода на С++, оттого и стало интересно